# C# Open Form from another Form Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In **Form1.cs** i have

```
public const int n = 30;
public TabPage[] tp = new TabPage[n];

private void toolStripSeparator1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RenameFunc rf = new RenameFunc();
    rf.ShowDialog();
}
```

In **RenameFunc.cs** i have

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

    if (textBox1.Text != null)
    /*Line 24 */    frm1.tp[Array.IndexOf(frm1.tp, frm1.tabControl1.SelectedTab)].Text = textBox1.Text;
    Application.Exit();
```

}

tabControl1 is also seted tu Public

in Line 24 i get error

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.get_SelectedTabInternal()
   at System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.get_SelectedTab()
   at Notepad1._0.RenameFunc.button1_Click_1(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\C#\Notepad1.0\Notepad1.0\RenameFunc.cs:line 24

How to correct ?

Comment: You are hiding something. :) What's `frm1.tp`? Why are you creating a new instance of `Form1`?

Comment: I would advise you not to direct access the tabControl from RenameFunc.cs. You should implement a Property in Form1.cs which contains the slected Tab of the tabcontrol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what `tp` is, but, I'm sure it's not initialized and this gives the exception.
The reason is easily found in the previous line

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
```

here you create a new instance of Form1. You are not referencing the first Form1 from which your RenameFunc has been called.

Perhaps you could pass a reference to the correct Form1 when you call RenameFunc, for example

```
RenameFunc rf = new RenameFunc(this);
```

and keep that reference in your RenameFunc internal vars

```
public partial class RenameFunc : Form
{
    private Form1 _caller = null;
    public RenameFunc(Form1 f)
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         _caller = f;       
    }
```

}

and in button1_Click_1 use that reference instead of new Form1

```
   if (textBox1.Text != null)           
        _caller.tp[Array.IndexOf(_caller.tp, _caller.tabControl1.SelectedTab)].Text =
                   textBox1.Text;           
   Application.Exit();
```

However a little explanation on tp would be beneficial

Comment: Why -1 ? That answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows,

```
 Form1 frm = (Form1)this.Parent;
```

You can access controls using `frm.Controls` and do wat u like to do with it.

Comment: you can use frm.Controls.FindControl(urcontrolname) as ur control

Answer (score 0):

Its coming back with the error to tell you that  `frm1.tabControl1.SelectedTab` is not found in `frm1.tp`, none of your code associates the 30 tabpages in `tp` with `tabControl1` that you showed, so, by making a new copy of `form1` as `frm1`, then asking to place name of the tab page in the text box when looking for selected, the answer is, none of those new pages are selected.